# Ubuntu One behind proxy

Tags: ubuntu-one, proxy

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04.
I am behind a proxy server which requires authentication.

While setting up Ubuntu One, it is able to sign into my account( step 2 ), but when it comes to step 3( Select Sync Folders ), it just keeps on saying gathering information and nothing happens.

How to make Ubuntu One work in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install the `ubuntuone-client-proxy` package, to be able to use Ubuntu One file sync from behind a proxy.